# Proof that if that if m is odd then gcd(5,2^m-1)=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Proof that if m is odd then gcd(5,2^m-1)=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euGAJ.png)

Comment: $$2^{2m+1}-1 \equiv 2(-1)^m-1 \in \{1,2\}\pmod{5}$$

Comment: Quelle est votre question exactement?

Comment: i need a proof of the =>

Comment: $\!\!\bmod 5\!:\,\ \left[1\equiv 2^{\large m}\right]^{\large 2}\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 4^{\large m}\!\equiv (-1)^{\large m}\!\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, 5\mid 2\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$5$ is a prime number.

So, if a positive integer $d$ divides simultaneously $5$ and $2^n-1$ and if $d\neq 1$, then ...